# Make a program that outputs its own MD5 hash

Tags: code-golf, quine, hashing

Challenge: make a program that outputs a [MD5 hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) of its source code.

You should not use tricks that would be considered cheating in a quine sense (discussed [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine)).

Using built-in functions and external libraries is allowed. The program should be a full program (not a function/subroutine). Code-golf: shortest solution (byte count) wins.

Comment: Please include sufficient information regarding MD5 hashes directly in the post such that Wikipedia could be used as a supplement rather than a necessary resource. Challenges should be as self-contained as possible.

Comment: This is a borderline duplicate of [the plain quine challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69/3808). A large portion of the answers can simply be copied over here with `print()` replaced with `print(md5())`.

Comment: In what format should the hash be printed? Hex with lowercase letters, or with uppercase, or base64, or binary, or raw binary?

Comment: Its a good question, but definitely a dup of http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8947/cryptographic-quine-variant.  Perhaps that one needs some more answers :)